# Transfer domain from one AWS account to another AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-route53

I'm trying to transfer a domain name from one AWS account to another AWS account using AWS CLI. When I try to transfer the domain I get the following error:

`Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://route53domains.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"`

I'm using the following command to transfer the domain

`aws route53domains transfer-domain-to-another-aws-account --domain-name <value> --account-id <value> --profile personal`

I checked the aws config file and it looks fine. It looks like this:

```
[profile personal]
aws_access_key_id = somekey
aws_secret_access_key = somesecretkey
region = us-west-2
```

I've also made sure that the user has the correct permission. The user has the following permission

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "route53domains:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and also has the `AdministratorAccess` AWS managed policy.

To make sure I can communicate with AWS. I ran a simple command `aws s3 ls --profile personal` and it works. AWS responds back with the contents of S3.

The version of AWS CLI I have installed is
`aws-cli/2.0.18 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/19.4.0 botocore/2.0.0dev22`

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will need to specify `--region us-east-1` because Amazon Route 53 is a global service.

Comment: I've tried with `--region` e.g. aws `route53domains transfer-domain-to-another-aws-account --domain-name <value> --account-id <value> --region us-east-1 --profile personal` and its not worked. Can you give an example of what the command should look like?

Comment: From the doc, the command should look like `transfer-domain-to-another-aws-account --domain-name <value> --account-id <value> [--cli-input-json | --cli-input-yaml] [--generate-cli-skeleton <value>] [--cli-auto-prompt <value>]`. So im not sure why its not working

Comment: When I tried your command, I got the same error. Then I added `--region us-east-1` and it changed to complaining about the values I provided. Hence, my advice to change the region. What is the error you receive when you use `--region us-east-1`?

Comment: I'm getting `Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://route53domains.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"`.  The exact command im running is `aws route53domains transfer-domain-to-another-aws-account --domain-name someDomain.co.uk --account-id --region eu-west-1 12345678 --profile personal`

Comment: I've also made sure the default region in `.aws/config` matches `--profile` in the AWS CLI command

Comment: From the docs `https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/route53domains/transfer-domain-to-another-aws-account.html` It doesn't mention anything about specifying the region.

Comment: The command you just quoted includes `--region eu-west-1`. You should use `--region us-east-1`.

Comment: It's worked now. Adding the region has sorted the issue. Thank you for the help

Comment: Transferring route53 domains had the issue!

Comment: Thanks, it resolved my problem! I tried without the region, and then I tried with my own region, and both didn't work. Only "--region us-east-1" worked. Thanks once more

Answer (score 0):

I was going to rebuff the answer given by John Rotenstein but, on closer examination, it is indeed correct. It could do with some more detail though, so I shall elaborate.

The OP didn't miss anything, this need for `--region us-east-1` (and **only** `us-east-1`) to be included in the command is not mentioned in either the [route53domains docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/route53domains/index.html#cli-aws-route53domains) or the docs of the subcommand, [transfer-domain-to-another-aws-account](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/route53domains/transfer-domain-to-another-aws-account.html). It does pop up on the [list-operations page](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/route53domains/list-operations.html) but even there, it's not as noticable as it could be^^.

^^: *You might ask yourself, why it isn't builtin to the `awscli` to default to `us-east-1` for this set of commands anyway, since there are no other options?*